# Mouting OpenShift secrets into volumes / files with restricted access rights

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, mount, secret-key

I am mounting an OpenShift 3.11 secret into a container by virtue of this new section inside the container's element in `dc.spec.template.spec.containers:

```
volumeMounts:
- name: my-secret
  mountPath: /mnt/my-secret
  readOnly: true
```

and that new section into `dc.spec.template.spec.containers`:

```
volumes:
- name: my-secret
  secret:
    secretName: my-secret
```

My `my-secret` has been created from a private key like so:

```
oc create secret generic my-secret \
  --type=kubernetes.io/ssh-auth \
  --from-file=ssh-privatekey=my-private-key
```

At container runtime, I find the armored private key in a file `/mnt/my-secret/ssh-privatekey`. How can I ensure that only the UID which runs the container (a random UID under OpenShift rules) can read from that file, i.e. enforce a file mode akin to `0400`?

Comment: Try setting the ``defaultMode`` for the secret in the ``volumes`` definition. See what it is for by running: ``oc explain dc.spec.template.spec.volumes.secret.defaultMode``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `dc.spec.template.spec.volumes.secret.defaultMode` (as suggested in the comment) to `0644` seems to have the desired effect on the private key in a file symlinked from `/mnt/my-secret/ssh-privatekey`.

Comment: I’m setting the same defaultMode value on the secret to 256, but my key file ends up with an additional group read permission anyhow. Is there another setting in the spec which affects the permissions of the mounted file?